# libgit2sharp Repository "safe handle has been closed"

Tags: git, repository, dispose, using-statement, libgit2sharp

Is there any problem with instantiating a Repository object twice in the same method, each time wrapped in a separate `using()` statement :

```
using(var repo = new Repository({local-path}, new RepositoryOptions()) {
// do some stuff with repo
}

// do some other stuff not related to repo

using(var repo = new Repository({local-path}, new RepositoryOptions()) {
// do even more stuff with repo
}
```

For such a code-block with this structure, in the `do even more stuff` block I'm experiencing a run-time exception `safe handle has been closed`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any problem with instantiating a Repository object twice in the same method, each time wrapped in a separate using() statement

Instantiating a `Repository` instance is quite cheap, so there's no problem with this approach.

However, one has to keep in mind the following things

- Objects (`Reference`s, `Commit`s, `Tree`s, ..) returned through by the LibGit2Sharp library are expected to be used during the lifetime of the `Repository` (ie. before it's disposed). Not doing so may lead to `ObjectDisposedException` being thrown.
- For performance reasons, **[libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/)**, the underlying native library does a lot of caching. This cache is purged every time the `Repository` is disposed. As such, by relying on different instances of the `Repository` type, you may prevent one from benefiting from this performance bumps.

> I'm experiencing a run-time exception safe handle has been closed.

This may happen if you reuse in the second `using` block some objects that originate from the first one.

Comment: @BaltoStar Was this answer any helpful?

Comment: I think this response was very useful and gave it an up-vote.